# MYSQL Using UPDATE, WHEN THEN with a NULL value

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to figure out why I'm not getting a result from a MySQL Query I'm running.

I'm trying to replace a `NULL` value with a number with in a query, but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Here's my query:

```
UPDATE Details
SET HowHear_ID = CASE HowHear_ID
  WHEN '' THEN 25   
  WHEN NULL THEN 25                         
  WHEN 7  THEN 25
  WHEN 8  THEN 5
  WHEN 16 THEN 25
  WHEN 17 THEN 16
END
WHERE HowHear_ID IN ('',NULL,7,8,16,17)
```

This Query will effect all but the `NULL` values.

What am I doing wrong??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No value will ever equal (or "unequal") `NULL` in SQL. Understand the following truth table:

```
NULL = NULL yields NULL   -- not FALSE!
NULL != NULL yields NULL  -- not TRUE!
[ANY] = NULL yields NULL  -- not FALSE!
[ANY] != NULL yields NULL -- not TRUE!
```

Since the following are equivalent...

```
[expression] IN (a, b, c)
[expression] = ANY (a, b, c)
[expression] = a OR [expression] = b OR [expression] = c
```

... you cannot put `NULL` on the right hand side of an `IN predicate`. Interestingly, things get even worse when you put `NULL` on the right hand side of a `NOT IN predicate`:

```
[expression] NOT IN (a, b, c)
[expression] != ANY (a, b, c)
[expression] != a AND [expression] != b AND [expression] != c
```

If `b` were `NULL`, the whole expression will become `NULL` (or maybe `FALSE`), but never `TRUE`. This is also the case for `NOT IN (subselect)` predicates! So, never do this:

```
[expression] NOT IN (NULL, 1, 2)
```

The correct solution in your case uses a `NULL predicate` instead. Do this:

```
UPDATE Details
SET HowHear_ID = CASE 
  WHEN HowHear_ID = ''    THEN 25   
  WHEN HowHear_ID IS NULL THEN 25  -- Use a NULL predicate here
  WHEN HowHear_ID = 7     THEN 25
  WHEN HowHear_ID = 8     THEN 5
  WHEN HowHear_ID = 16    THEN 25
  WHEN HowHear_ID = 17    THEN 16
END
WHERE HowHear_ID IN ('',7,8,16,17)
   OR HowHear_ID IS NULL           -- Use a NULL predicate here
```

Or this:

```
WHERE COALESCE(HowHear_ID, '') IN ('',7,8,16,17)
```

Comment: Good explanation. However, I still have the NULL values after the Query. It does not replace the NULL values with the 25 that I'am trying to achieve.

Comment: @Monty: I see, well you don't need that `CASE` expression, since you're updating everything to 25. See the updated answer

Comment: Sorry, I left part of the code out as I have over 900 lines for it. They update to different number not only 25. I'll edit that.

Comment: @Monty: OK, I fixed my `UPDATE` statement example, to match yours. The same `NULL`-related rules apply to the `CASE` expression

Comment: @Monty: No worries. SQL `NULLs` keep surprising me time and again, myself :-) For completeness, I'll update what happens when you put `NULL` in a `NOT IN predicate`!

Answer (score 1):

You can't reference `NULL` in a `WHERE` clause and get the results you expect. `NULL` behaves differently to other values.

If you need to reference it, you need to use the `isnull()` function.

in your case, you would write something like this:

```
WHERE HowHear_ID IN ('',7,8,16,17) or isnull(HowHear_ID)
```

By the way, you haven't specified the data type of the field. I assume it's an integer though. In that case, it might be better to check for zero rather than an empty string? (if it isn't an integer, then perhaps it should be)

Comment: This runs, but does not replace the NULL values with the 25. What am I missing?

Comment: you need to do the same for the `when` clause too. Change the null to `isnull()`

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that with

```
WHERE HowHear_ID IN ('',7,8,16,17) OR HowHear_ID IS NULL
```